# Double ArrayList in double array adding

Tags: java, arraylist, escaping

I Define an ArrayList as below;

```
static ArrayList<Double[]> aryList1 = new ArrayList<Double[]>();
```

and i wish to add this into the arraylist

```
double[] a = new double[]{0.1,0.2};
arylist1.add(a);
```

but it show error at the

```
arylist1.add(a)
```

...add cannot be applied to double ArrayList.

Comment: `double[] != Double[]`

Comment: arylist1.add(a) should be aryList1.add(a).

Comment: auto-boxing doesn't happen here as you may have thought..this is because `double[]` is a reference type and so you can't expect any auto-boxing here

Answer (score 6):

Try with capital D for double e.g. `Double[] a = new Double[]{0.1,0.2};`

You are trying to add a lowercase `double` which is a *primitive* type to the arraylist that you have defined as `Double` which is a *wrapper* object.

Comment: You definitely can add a `double[]` to a `List<double[]>`.

Comment: to a list<double[]> yes, but not to a list<Double[]>

Answer (score 3):

**[Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html)** is a *class* while **[double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)** is a *primitive*.

You have `static ArrayList<Double[]> aryList1 = new ArrayList<Double[]>();` which has `Double[]` and not `double[]`. So you should:

```
Double[] a = new Double[]{0.1,0.2};
```

Or, you can change the *declaration* to:

```
static ArrayList<double[]> aryList1 = new ArrayList<double[]>();
```

Another error you have:

`arylist1.add(a)` should be `aryList1.add(a)` (Java is case sensitive).